# Javascript trigger a URL on Homepage Load

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup, magento-1.7

We are moving our website from hosting.

I was wondering why the Youama extension is not loading on our homepage. This is our website in old hosting  as you can see upon loading the homepage the extension is loaded right away. But in our new hosting which is an exact replica, no changes or modifications added, as you can see it's not loading the extension, but if you click the Login at the top it will run the extension.

Can someone here please help me identify the issue? Or maybe give me a solution wherein I can manually add a Javascript code so I can trigger such event?

Looking forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hard coded links to the old site, see the example below. Change those links to the new domain.

```
function isUserLoggedIn()
{
    $.ajax({
            //Update to http://electricbot.com/lipstickboutique/
            url: "http://lipstickboutiquewholesale.co.uk/checkuser.php",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000
        })
        .done(function(data){
            userStatus = data;
        })
        ;
}
```

Comment: Please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] as it lacks an MCVE. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Comment: where can I see this?

Comment: thanks @benni_mac_b I found it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript error that blocks the  Youama extension to execute.
Maybe you are still sending ajax request to old url: There is some kind of CORS prevention on the back-end, which results in ajax request failing.

Comment: where do I see this?